# How to typeset mathematical expressions in Facebook posts?

Tags: mathjax

Could anyone kindly explain to me how to use MathJax to typeset mathematical expressions in Facebook posts? This [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHvsop4fu20) shows that it can be done, but it does not contain any explanation. Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it.

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try insteead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.